# WPF: bind property from MainWindow.xaml cause an error

Tags: wpf, binding

So I have this `view model`:

```
public class WiresharkFiles : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<WiresharkFile> List { get; set; }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private bool _inUse;
    private int _packets;
    private bool _hasItems;

    public WiresharkFiles()
    {
        List = new ObservableCollection<WiresharkFile>();
        HasItems = false;
        List.CollectionChanged += List_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void List_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        HasItems = List.Count > 0;
    }

    public bool InUse
    {
        get { return _inUse; }
        set
        {
            _inUse = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("InUse");
        }
    }

    public int Packets
    {
        get { return _packets; }
        set
        {
            _packets = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Packets");
        }
    }

    public bool HasItems
    {
        get { return _hasItems; }
        set
        {
            _hasItems = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("HasItems");
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
private WiresharkFiles caps;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent(); 
    caps = new WiresharkFiles();
}
```

**Window.Resources**

```
<Window.Resources>
   <Convertors:CollectionHasItemsConverter x:Key="CollectionHasItemsConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

**Converter**

```
public class CollectionHasItemsConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And base of my collection item (empty or not) i want to enable/disable my `Button`:

```
<Button Name="btnDeleteAll"
        Click="btnDeleteAll_Click"
        IsEnabled="{Binding Path=(caps.HasItems),Converter={StaticResource CollectionHasItemsConverter}}">
```

And i got this `error`:

> XamlParseException: Type reference cannot find type named
>   '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation}caps'.

Comment: In addition to the caps being a private variable and data context not set, the round brackets in the binding is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you're associating your `DataContext` with the `caps` property.

Make sure you have a public property because the WPF engine isn't running from within your class and won't be able to access the `private WiresharkFiles caps;` variable. Try the following:

```
private WiresharkFiles caps;
public WiresharkFiles Files { get { return caps; } }
```

with a corresponding

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent(); 
    caps = new WiresharkFiles();
    DataContext = Files;
}
```

Your XAML will then bind to Files as follows

```
IsEnabled="{Binding Path=HasItems}"
```

**Update** You'll need to have a look at implementing and binding to commands for the button which will make it a lot better. [Look at this article for info on implementing and dealing with commands.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview)

Comment: Where i need to put this: public WiresharkFiles Files { get { return caps; } } ?

Comment: Next to the definition of caps would be fine. Let me update my answer to show it

Comment: No error now but the button is enable although the list empty and i can see that my converter not even executed

Comment: "HasItems" is already a bool value.. why do you need a converter?

Comment: OK i have change it and the button still enable

Comment: @ShivaniKatukota is on to something, try running it without the converter to see. In this case it isn't necessary to use a value converter if the source and target type are both `bool`

Comment: I tried your code with the changes @Fabulous mentioned and removed the converter, it works fine!

Comment: What i need to do with the link you gave me ? why is good for my purposes ?

Comment: If it's working as you said then you can do without it, but otherwise you can bind buttons to commands using MVVM as they are designed to handle the enabling and disabling of buttons/menus etc. and other command related issues such as execution when the command is invoked

Answer (score 0):

caps is a private variable:

```
private WiresharkFiles caps;
```

In order to bind, it would have to be a public property:

```
public WiresharkFiles caps {get;set;}
```

You would also have to set the datacontext of the window to itself. Something like:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

or
In your window tag put:

```
 DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

I don't see how this relates to your initial question but you can use dot notation in binding.
You can bind:

```
{Binding AnObservableCollection.Count}
```

And you can compare that to 0 in a datatrigger. With a button and a bound command if you want to disable it then I'd use the canexecute of icommand and return false if you have no entries or whatever your logic is.

Comment: No error now but the button is enable although the list empty and i can see that my converter not even executed

Comment: `Path=(caps.HasItems)` is also invalid here (the parentheses have a different meaning than what OP thinks), it should be `Path=caps.HasItems`,

Comment: This is what i have: IsEnabled="{Binding Path=HasItems}"

Comment: Can i move this.DataContext = this to XAML ?

Comment: You can bind the datacontext of the window to itself. I added that to my post above.

Comment: The thing is that i have several collections that i want to bind (each of them is WiresharkFiles  object) to different Buttons so i can user this DataContext 3 times ? or maybe i need to use another approach ?

Comment: I don't follow why you'd be binding a collection to a button. That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: In my application i have several ListView, each of them hold MyData collections that inside specific class, and one of the properties of this is HasItems

Comment: Maybe i need to try another approach ?

Comment: Still don't really see how your observablecollections relate to a button and this description. I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: if my collection is empty i want my button will be disable, so i try to find a way how to hold 3 instances of my  view model that in each view model there is a collection with MyData